# CSS in embedded Vaadin applications not working

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

My Vaadin 24 components are embedded as described in https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/integrations/embedding/exporter

The DOM looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/web-component/xxx.js"></script>
<xxx id="vaadin-1" style="width: 100%"></xxx>
<xxx-view>
<vaadin-vertical-layout class="invisible" ...>
```

However jquery does not find nodes like $('.invisible')

Should this be listed under "Embedded Application Limitations"?

Comment: If `xxx-view` is your webcomponent, could it be, that jquery by default can not reach into the shadow-DOM?

Comment: yes, jquery cannot find it and the CSS (visibility: hidden) is ignored